# Unity 3D - Multiple Camera Switch Script by Keycode

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

im doing a little scene in Unity 3D with multiple cameras

Im trying to make a script to change camera pressing Keys 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

Each number goes to specific camera.

Any help aprreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: https://youtube.com

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete version of a script you can use to switch between cameras

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Camera> Cameras;

    private void Start()
    {
        EnableCamera(0);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            EnableCamera(0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            EnableCamera(1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
        {
            EnableCamera(2);
        }

        /*
         * If you want to add more cameras, you need to add
         * some more 'else if' conditions just like above
         */
    }

    private void EnableCamera(int n)
    {
        Cameras.ForEach(cam => cam.enabled = false);
        Cameras[n].enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Name the script `CameraSwitch` (full name `CameraSwitch.cs`), create a new GameObject in your scene or use an existing one, add the script to the GameObject (either from the `Add Component` menu or just drag-n-drop the script to your GameObject's inspector), then you need to expand property `Cameras` by clicking on it in the inspector, set the number of Camera (`Size`) to 3, and link your cameras in the following fields. Put the main camera first and don't leave a field blank or the script will fail.

If you need to add a new camera to the list, just add an `else if` condition besides the existing ones and don't forget to change the size of your list and link the new cameras in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code:

```
public Camera camera1;
public Camera camera2;
...

void Start()
{
    camera1.enabled = true;
    camera2.enabled = false;
    ...
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
    {
         camera1.enabled = true;
         camera2.enabled = false;
         ...
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
    {
         camera1.enabled = false;
         camera2.enabled = true;
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You can add other cameras like this. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, but i dont know what to put on start of the script and close this  script to unity recognize...  I saw another post with this code, but i need the start and the close sintax.

Answer (score 0):

```
public GameObject cam1;
public GameObject cam2;
public GameObject cam3;


if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) {

cam1.SetActive(true);
cam2.SetActive(false);
cam3.SetActive(false);

}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
{

cam1.SetActive(false);
cam2.SetActive(true);
cam3.SetActive(false);

}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3)) {

cam1.SetActive(false);
cam2.SetActive(false);
cam3.SetActive(true);

}
```